# how to create an oracle form

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

I am looking for a source to teach me how to create an oracle form. I don't want to create a form by using oracle form builder, I would like to understand how to create a *.fmb file.

Do you have any good source to read about it? I would like to create a custom IDE that's why I want to know how I can create an Oracle form.

please advice me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the open api functionality in oracle forms to make your own fmb files.
For more info [read this link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97335_02/apps.102/a73073/d2kopen.htm)

Comment: it was so useful tq. I am checking it.

Comment: In later versions of the product I think the C API was replaced by a Java version, JDAPI.

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to do that.

Back in 1990's, Forms 3.0, when a form source was an .INP file which was a pure TXT file, it had its own structure so you might have tried to do everything in a text editor - define blocks, triggers, PL/SQL code, whatever. I don't know a single person who did that - that's what Forms is used for, so that you - as a developer - could pay attention to development and let Forms do the boring job for you.

Today, .FMB is not a textual file at all so you can't even do that.

I'd suggest you to learn how to develop good/fast/effective/etc. Forms applications, and - again - let Forms do the rest.

As of the rest of your question (creating a custom IDE), did you try to create a *query builder*? It is way simpler than creating a form, but still quite complex and certainly isn't something you can do in a matter of days.

Anyway, good luck with anything you're up to, I admire your enthusiasm.